# How to find all open/active connections in DB2 (8.x)

Tags: sql, db2

I'm currently working with Db2 Enterprise Server V 8.2 with FixPak 10

And I want to retrieve list of all the open active connections with an instance.

In Oracle there is a utility program called "Top Session" which does the similar task. Is there any equivalent in DB2?

Comment: In order to see the connections, the user should have at least sysmon authority at instance level.

Answer (score 10):

To get more detailed information from list applications:

```
db2 list applications for database {dbName} show detail
```

For applications with lots of active connections it is useful to pipe the results to `grep` to find only the threads currently executing or locked.

```
db2 list applications for database {dbName} show detail | grep -i "executing"
```

and

```
db2 list applications for database {dbName} show detail | grep -i "lock"
```

Answer (score 6):

CLP:

```
db2 list applications
```

QUERY:

```
SELECT * FROM SYSIBM.APPLICATIONS
SELECT * FROM SYSIBM.SESSION
```

Comment: I am not sure these queries work in DB2 v8. Administrative views are part of DB2 since version 9.1. And the schema is not sysibm but sysibmadm. More information in http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/topic/com.ibm.db2.udb.admin.doc/doc/r0022011.htm

Comment: In DB2 9.7.5 I'Ve found the schema is SYSIBMADM, so query is: select * from sysibmadm.applications ;

Answer (score 3):

The command you seek is:

```
LIST APPLICATIONS
```

In the DB2 Command Center there is a tool which list the applications and displays them in a human friendly format as well.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you are searching for below query.

```
SELECT
    AUTHID,
    APPL_NAME,
    CLIENT_NNAME,
    AGENT_ID,
    APPL_ID,
    APPL_STATUS
FROM
    SYSIBMADM.APPLICATIONS
```