# SQL Connection ClientInfo

Tags: java, sql, database-connection

I am writing a Java Application in which I am connecting to a DB2 database and after getting the connection, I am setting the client info for that connection using the following code:

```
String clientprogname = "MY PROGRAM";  //Progname
String clientname = "user1";  // The name of the End-User

con.setClientInfo("ApplicationName", clientprogname);
con.setClientInfo("ClientUser", clientname);

con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 WHERE 0 = 1").executeQuery();
// Execute SQL to force extended client information to be sent to the server

LogFile.log("ApplicationName: " + con.getClientInfo("ApplicationName"));
LogFile.log("ClientUser: " + con.getClientInfo("ClientUser"));
```

I am aware that I can get the client info using `con.getClientInfo`, but is the client information stored in the database? According to the [Java Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#setClientInfo%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29), the client information is stored in a suitable location in the database (for example in a special register, session parameter, or system table column). Is there an SQL statement which I can execute to see a list of all open connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.admin.doc/doc/r0005865.htm) you can get it from the special registers, here's an older [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261512/how-to-find-all-open-active-connections-in-db2-8-x) that references the same thing.

Edited:

This is also a nice link that lists a number of useful statements [dbForums](http://www.dbforums.com/db2/1642489-db-usage-statistics.html)

Comment: On DB2 9.7: select substr(APPL_NAME,1,30) from SYSIBMADM.APPLICATIONS

Answer (score 1):

The support for `getClientInfo` and the datastorage location is database dependent. You will need to check the driver and database documentation to find out how it is handled for you database / driver.

Comment: I am connecting to the DB2 database (DB2 v9.7.400.501) using the IBM DB2 Type 4 driver (db2jcc4.jar). I tried to search in the DB2 documentation but no luck :/