# Session information in DB2 v9.1

Tags: sql, oracle, db2

I am trying to rewrite my queries from Oracle to DB2 V9.1.

For example I have the following query, which returns sessions for a specific program and user.

```
SELECT sid FROM V$SESSION WHERE PROGRAM = 'example' AND USERNAME = 'testuser';
```

I haven´t found the right table/tables in DB2 which store this information. Where is the session information stored in DB2?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find all open/active connections in DB2 (8.x)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/261512/how-to-find-all-open-active-connections-in-db2-8-x)

Comment: No its not, the Tables SYSIBM.APPLICATIONS and SYSIBM.SESSION doesnt exist in DB2 Version 9.1

Comment: [APPLICATIONS](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2.udb.admin.doc%2Fdoc%2Fr0022011.htm) does.

Comment: Why do you want to migrate to an obsolete DB2 version? Here, in SOF, we use to provide information about the most recent versions.

Comment: allright, its another schema than in the other thread, its SYSIBMADM.APPLICATIONS, but the Session table is not in the same schema

Comment: why does it interrest u, why i want to migrate? if u have an idea tell me, but stop flaming

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken all the information you probably want is in that table:  `SELECT agent_id FROM SYSIBMADM.APPLICATIONS WHERE appl_name = @program AND authid = @user`