# Db2: Get current connection details

Tags: database, db2, db2-luw

Is there a way in DB2 to fetch current connection details? I'm working on a requirement where I need to keep history of all inserts/updates on a table along with the details about the user who made the change. I'm looking for a way to retrieve current connection user's name, hostname and/or IP address from where the connection is made. We are using LUW DB2 v10.5.0.8

Comment: The answer depends on the Db2 (or DB2) version and platform, as well as the API the application uses. Unless you can provide these details, the question is too broad.

Comment: @mustaccio upvoted for noticing my inconsistent DB2 spelling

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `special registers` as pseudo-columns within `SQL` statements such as triggers:

```
SELECT 
 CURRENT TIMESTAMP,    
 SESSION_USER,
 CURRENT CLIENT_WRKSTNNAME
FROM
 SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
```

Source: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2-for-zos/11?topic=elements-special-registers

Comment: awesome.. this works like a charm. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

[May be you are seraching for the below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62642694/5227954)

Maybe you are searching for below query.

```
SELECT
    AUTHID,
    APPL_NAME,
    CLIENT_NNAME,
    AGENT_ID,
    APPL_ID,
    APPL_STATUS
FROM
    SYSIBMADM.APPLICATIONS
```