# DB2 query is consuming long time how do i solve it

Tags: sql, performance, db2, database-administration

If in an interview I am asked As a DB2 DBA how would you approach a job or a query which is consuming more time than normal? Which commands would you use and what all steps would you take to resolve it?

Comment: Please read this thread
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261512/how-to-find-all-open-active-connections-in-db2-8-x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261512/how-to-find-all-open-active-connections-in-db2-8-x)

Answer (score 0):

If it is a job I would use db2mon.sh as a starting point, if it is a query I would first try db2advis to see if it recommends any indexes.

Answer (score 0):

The Db2 Knowledge Center has a section on "Troubleshooting" which includes [Troubleshooting Db2 Servers](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.trb.doc/doc/c0024293.html) and there is a section on [Troubleshooting SQL Performance](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.perf.doc/doc/c0005414.html?pos=2) which mentions [`db2mon`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.perf.doc/doc/t0070377.html).

There is also a section on [Performance Tuning](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.perf.doc/doc/c0005414.html).  As a DBA, it is worth reading all these sections (at least once anyway).